# Redirect https www to just http

Tags: redirect

In serach results my site has https://www.  and in Pagespeed Insights there is message "Avoid multiple page redirects"

I would like to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

What is best way to do that in htaccess to avoid SEO problems?

I know there are many questions and replies regarding this topic but I don't know enough about redirects and want to avoid wrong way to do it since I was building pagerank for a long time

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it seems good

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I don't know is it important to have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

and does it put load on server